# How to define custom operator for working with tensors with multiple indices?

Tags: tensors, field-theory

I've symmetric tensor $h(z)$ with rank $s$.

Instead of writing symmetric tensor with its components I use the following notation

$h^{(s)}(z;a) = \sum_{\mu_i}(\prod_{i=1}^{s}a^{\mu_i})h^{(s)}_{\mu_1\mu_2 ... \mu_s}(z)$

And I use the following $*_{a}$ operator for contracting tensors in this notation

$*_{a} = \frac{1}{(s!)^2}\prod_{i=1}^{s} \overset{\leftarrow}{\partial^{\mu_i}_{a}} \overset{\rightarrow}{\partial_{\mu_i}^{a}} $

Arrows on derivatives show the direction of differentiation.

with this operator, tensor contraction can be written without components.

$g^{(s)}(z;a) *_a h^{(s)}(z;a) = g^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_s} h_{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_s} = gh$

Now I'm trying to implement this operator in Wolfram Mathematica, but all my attempts failed.
Is it possible to define such an operator in Mattematica, and if yes how can I achieve that?

Comment: "I use the following notation" - how is it represented in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Melik Karapetyan  Do you have a clear example of using this definition?

Comment: I don't get it. Your method is a very obfuscated way of writing `Flatten[g].Flatten[h]`.

Comment: I've took the notation from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.1358.pdf 

I'm trying to automate the computation with this notation using Mathematica and searching a way to represent it in Matematica. The clear example of using this definition can be found on Section 1 of that paper.